# Pig: extracting email details from raw text using REGEX

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to extract email details from raw text using pig.

Here's the sample data:

```
Sample data for email abc.123@gmail.com
Sample data for email xyz@abc.com
```

I am trying with REGEX method, Regular expression i took from: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

here's the script:

```
A = Load '----' using PigStorage as (value: chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(value, '^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$')) AS (f1: chararray)
dump B;
```

After dumping the output into the terminal, i am getting blank output:

```
()
()
```

Is there any problem in script syntax?

Please share some links also regarding regular expression writing, it would be very much helpful.

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For following input data

```
abc.123@gmail.com
xyz@abc.com
```

Output of your code is

```
.123 .com
     .com
```

So there are couple of problems in your code

1. You need to add parenthesis around the whole regex to capture the complete email address.  The code should then work if you have only one token (word or email-id) in each line
2. If each input line can be a sentence, then you have to first [tokenize](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#TOKENIZE) and then on tokens you can to do regex match.

The reason that the regex you have works only on token and not on line is "^" indicates beginning of string and "$" indicates end of string, so the match is going to successful only when the entire line is an email-id which means you can have only one token per line.

Comment: Hi Manish! You should accept @Bharat's answer if it is helpful to you (it looks like it was, since you had no further questions for him)(and also it seems correct to me)